# Can a class be subclass of more than one class?

Tags: java, superclass

While i was working on my assignment on Java, I created 3 classes, lets say class 1, class2 and class3

Then I tried to define one of the classes in the following way:

```
public class class1 extends class2 extends class3{
```

To be honest, I was almost sure it would not work and in fact did not.

So I wanted to know If I could create a single subclass for two different super classes. Thank You!

Comment: No, you can't. And if you search the wide web, you'll find plenty of explanations. Please Google before you ask simple questions.

Comment: That is not possible, but there are "work-arounds". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132528/class-extending-more-than-one-class-java

Comment: NO!!!!! Thats basics of Java..

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). Java does not support this.

Multiple inheritance is hard for compiler writers to implement - mainly because of the [diamond problem](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-diamond-problem/).

Except - in Java 8 there are interfaces with default methods. This allows sort of a light-weight version of multiple inheritance.

Comment: Multiple interfaces + default methods

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. In Java you can extend only one base class. You can however implement from multiple interfaces

Answer (score 0):

For java,no.

in "Tink in java"1.8 Single Root extends structure has mentioned  that.

but in C++,yes.