# How to extend class with two another classes?

Tags: java, android

I want to extend my class with 2 other classes Fragment and Activity.
I tried this:

```
public class Frist extends Fragment , Activity 
{
      .....
      .....
}
```

But it's not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: like this but it Does not work

Comment: Interesting problem you have there, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836662/extending-from-two-classes. In short, you can't extend explicitly two classes.

Comment: Java does not support iheriting from multiple classes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15132549/2536878

Comment: ... `extends Fragment , activity` is a pure **nonsense**. It's a Fragment? Then it can't be an Activity. It's an Activity? Then it can't be a Fragment. You can't have an animal which is `cat AND dog` at the same time.

Comment: @DerGol...lum, but you can have an animal which is both a Vertebrate and a Pet, or an animal which is both a Bird and a Predator.

Comment: @DerGol...lum it's not nonsense since other languages (like C++) have *multiple inheritance* (and other features built upon this one, like *virtual inheritance*).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Sure. But, **as you should know**, as an **Android developer**, a `Fragment` is a **very different thing** from an `Activity`.

Comment: @Gol...lum ok, I thought you were talking about the mechanism itself.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski No, I was talking about Fragment and Activity. No matter, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend multiple classes. Why you can't extend fragment in another class?

Answer (score 1):

You should use decorator or composition pattern

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support multiple inheritance
Fragment and activity both are completely different thing.
If your want to make activity having fragment over it then  in android studio create project with **Activity with Fragment** instead of with **Blank activity** 

Then Automatically android studio will provide with some code having fragment and classes and xml for it.